# MDX Error while creating Calculated Measure

Tags: mdx

I am trying to create a calculated measure that finds the difference between two measures by using the following mdx query

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Available]
 AS  ([Measures].[Capacity days] ,[Project].[Projects by Name].[All],[Project].[Projects by Code].[All]) 
    -  ([Measures].[Worked Days]  ,EXCEPT([Project].[Projects by Name].[Project].MEMBERS,
[Project].[Projects by Name].[Project].&[1214]),[Version].[Version].[Combined],[Charge].[Charge].[All])
```

In case of second measure Worked Days I want to access it with respect to all projects except one ,so  am using `EXCEPT` function which results in the following error

" The  function expects a string or numeric expression for the  argument. A tuple set expression was used"

Is there any other way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is mixing tuples with sets. Perhaps you can check this [gentle introduction](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html) of MDX for main concepts and notations.

The second tuple is using a set (the result of EXCEPT) as its second member which is not possible. You could use the [aggregate](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Aggregate.html) function as following to compute the [Worked Days] over the members of this set instead :

```
AS    ( [Measures].[Capacity days], ... ) 
   -  Aggregate(
         Except ( 
           [Project].[Projects by Name].[Project].MEMBERS,
           [Project].[Projects by Name].[Project].&[1214] 
         ),
         ( [Measures].[Worked Days], ... )
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .Since Worked Days measure is a calculated one, the aggregate function doesn't work on it. I tired what u suggested but again resulted in the error stating that "Aggregate functions cannot be used on calculated members in the Measures dimension".

Comment: OK, might be a SSAS limitation; you can use the Sum() instead if it's consistent with the [Measures].[Worked Days] aggregation type. Or create a calculated member in a different dimension (other than [Measures]).

Comment: Thanks it worked. Since the aggregation type for that measure was sum changing Aggregation() to Sum() did the job.